# Stopping \MakeUppercase

Tags: formatting, titlecaps

I inherited a rather complex `.tex` file structure for a book and I have to make some adjustments now. One problem I have is, that I want to make a footnote in chapter-title. The title is by definition written in only CAPS (per `\MakeUppercase` and it's not the default `\chapter` but a customized version). I don't want the footnote to be written only in uppercases.
I can change the footnote by `\MakeLowercases` but obviously I don't want that either.

Furthermore I am grateful for any general tips to get into the TeX world.

Thanks in advance.

This is my try on the minimal example I created with a standard overleaf-file. The original file uses many other bibs and custom commands but i guess/ hope those are not necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\Ueberschrift}[1]{\protect\MakeUppercase{#1}\newline}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\Ueberschrift{Introduction\protect\footnote{This is the footnote text ABC}}
Random main text.

\end{document}
```

The problem is, that the footnote text in written in full CAPS and I want that to change to the original large and lower cases. I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try with ``\footnotemark`` and ``\footnotetext`` instead of only ``\footnote``? Also, you should add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) reproducing the problem, it will be helpful to others to answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I can't see how those two commands could help me but I tried to show an working example and hope it helps.

Comment: The textcase package has `\NoCaseChange` and other tools IIRC. But IMHO you should 1) rather try to adjust the output of `\section` in order to get a real heading (there are packages and classes for this) and 2) try to avoid footnotes in headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a mark for a footnote using `\footnotemark`, and specify the text after with `\footnotetext`. Using your example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Ueberschrift}[1]{\protect\MakeUppercase{#1}\newline}

\begin{document}

\Ueberschrift{Introduction\protect\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{This is the footnote text ABC}
Random main text.

\end{document}
```

renders
[image]

with the footnote
[image]

However, I agree with @cgnieder's comment that it would be a better idea to use a package (for example [`titlesec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)) to format section titles instead of defining new commands.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! :)
The problem is, that there are dozens of custom commands already defined by my predecessor and I only have to use these files once, so I don't want to change sth. fundamentally where I have no knowledge about.